# Telescope "blue book"

Tags: soft-question, telescopes

I have a telescope that I may be in the market to sell in the near future and am wondering if there is a good source to find its value in the used market. Although it's never been out of the box, it was given as a gift nearly 10 years ago and I have no idea what it might be worth. It's a Meade 114EQ-DH and I see a few on eBay that look similar but none that are in-box and in brand new condition. Is there a source of prices similar to a blue book for cars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a telescope blue book web site, but it's more for high-end telescopes:
http://www.telescopebluebook.com/

Unfortunately, 114mm reflectors like yours are a dime a dozen and have almost no resale value.  They are typical "department store junk telescopes."

Comment: _They are typical "department store junk telescopes."_ Helpful?

Answer (score 3):

The classified section of [cloudynights.com](http://www.cloudynights.com/) is extensive enough to be very useful for determining the market value of components.